# Hadoop : java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

when I run the hadoop job it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
11/10/06 13:12:49 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
11/10/06 13:12:49 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:54310/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/Har/.staging/job_201110051450_0007
11/10/06 13:12:49 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3923)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:523)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1379)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1377)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No valid local directories in property: mapred.local.dir
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLocalPath(Configuration.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getLocalPath(JobConf.java:457)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress.<init>(JobInProgress.java:401)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker.submitJob(JobTracker.java:3921)
    ... 11 more

Streaming Job Failed!
```

How can I resolve this?

Thank you

Comment: Look in `mapred-site.xml` and check the `mapred.local.dir` property.  Is there a comma-separated list of directories there?  If so, do you have read and write permissions to those directories?

Comment: in the doc I followed, it never asks to set this value, http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/, but i'll try

Answer (score 3):

mapred.local.dir need to be configured properly. check whether it is configured in mapred-site or hdfs-site. The directory should be existing. User who executes the job should have proper permission on this directory

Comment: You dont need to , the default value is ${hadoop.tmp.dir}/mapred/local